In de Finetti probability, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and uniform on naturals, are $\max(X_1, X_2)$, $X_1 + X_2$, etc also?
The de Finetti probability theory generalizes the usual countable additivity requirement to finite additivity instead, and in so doing, allows for the uniform distribution to exist on the natural numbers. The resulting distribution is fairly interesting; in particular, we have that $P(n \in 2\Bbb N) = 1/2$, $P(n \in 3\Bbb N) = 1/3$, and in general $P(n \in k\Bbb N) = 1/k$.
Now suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both independent and uniformly distributed on the naturals. We can then look at the derived random variables
$$\max(X_1, X_2)$$
$$\min(X_1, X_2)$$
$$X_1 + X_2$$
In the de Finetti theory, are each of these also identically and also uniformly distributed on the natural numbers?
One would intuitively think that these would all be different and non-uniform. This is certainly what happens if you look at the behavior for each of those if we model $X_1$ and $X_2$ as uniformly distributed on $[0, N]$ as $N \to \infty$, for instance. I've also seen alternative generalized probability theories using ultrafilters where I think these would all be different distributions. But I'm not sure if the de Finetti theory is strong enough to differentiate between these.
In the de Finetti theory, for any one to be different from any other, we'd need to show there is at least one event with different probability mass. But I think we should still have $P(n \in k\Bbb N) = 1/k$: I don't see how taking the min, max, or sum, for instance, should change anything about that. In fact, for the sum, it's fairly easy to prove that it won't. So does there actually exist any subset of $\Bbb N$ which has different probability with any of these three than the original uniform distribution?

I'll just note that it looks like, for instance, $X_1 \cdot X_2$ really are different: the probability that the product is divisible by 6, for instance, is $5/12$ rather than $1/6$. So it isn't always the same. I'm not sure if we get something different with min, max, and sum, though.

Can you give a nice reference describing this "de Finetti probability theory"?

I don't have one offhand - you can probably find one on Google - but the basic idea is that the de Finetti axioms are the same as the Kolmogorov ones, but with countable additivity relaxed to finite additivity.
